# What divisibility function is between GCD and LCM with three inputs?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, lattice-orders

It is known that, for positive integers, $\text{GCD}(x,y)\cdot\text{LCM}(x,y)=x\cdot y$. I wanted to generalize this to three variables:

$$\text{GCD}(x,y,z)\cdot F(x,y,z)\cdot\text{LCM}(x,y,z)=x\cdot y\cdot z.$$

What function $F$ would make this true? We could use this equation as a definition of $F$; but a better definition comes from prime factorization:

$$x=\prod_{\text{prime }p}p^{v_p(x)}$$

$$\text{GCD}(x,y,z)=\prod_{\text{prime }p}p^{\min(v_p(x),v_p(y),v_p(z))}$$

$$F(x,y,z)=\prod_{\text{prime }p}p^{\text{mid}(v_p(x),v_p(y),v_p(z))}$$

$$\text{LCM}(x,y,z)=\prod_{\text{prime }p}p^{\max(v_p(x),v_p(y),v_p(z))}$$

where, also by definition, $(x',y',z')=(\min(x,y,z),\text{mid}(x,y,z),\max(x,y,z))$ is a permutation of $(x,y,z)$ such that $x'\leq y'\leq z'$. Since $x'+y'+z'=x+y+z$, the triple product equation follows.

It also follows that the three functions have divisibility relations

$$\text{GCD}(x,y,z)|F(x,y,z)|\text{LCM}(x,y,z).$$

Now here's the **question:** Can $F$ be defined directly in terms of multiplication and divisibility relations, without using prime factorization or the division operation? (In particular, I want something that works when some of $x,y,z$ are $0$.)

The other two functions can be defined by

$$\text{GCD}(x,y,z)=\max\{w\mid w|x,w|y,w|z\}$$

$$\text{LCM}(x,y,z)=\min\{w\mid x|w,y|w,z|w\}$$

(and here $\max$ can mean either $w'\leq w$ or $w'|w$). But from the example

$$x=2^2\cdot3,\;y=3^2\cdot5,\;z=5^2\cdot2,$$

$$F(x,y,z)=2\cdot3\cdot5,$$

we see that $F(x,y,z)$ does not divide and is not divided by any of $x,y,z$.

Comment: Then you just want a definition for which $F(x,y,z)$ is defined when one is zero, and it doesn't matter what the definition is (as in, it could be $F(0,2,5) = \pi$ and it would be ok?)

Comment: The definition should be uniform across all cases (not piecewise), whether $0$ is involved or not. I expect that to produce the same result as my answer, but maybe it's not unique.

Comment: My concern is that $LCM(0,2,5) = 0$ is itself a special case.  If you define it uniformly as $\text{LCM}(x,y,z)=\min\{w\mid x|w,y|w,z|w\}$ then the minimum would need to be taken over a set which includes $0,$ but then we'd have $LCM(6,10,15) = 0,$ rather than $30$ as is common (this is what my initial question was regarding).  I don't see much reason to have a "uniform" definition (which is a concept that is fairly hard to differentiate from "piecewise") for $F$ when we don't seem to have one for the $LCM$

Comment: It's not a special case if we use $\min$ in the sense of divisibility; everything divides $0$, so $0$ is actually a maximum, not a minimum. I already suggested this by "$w'\leq w$ vs $w'|w$". I agree that "uniform" and "piecewise" are difficult to distinguish.

Comment: Fair enough.  It wasn't apparent to me that your comment of $w' \leq w$ v. $ w' \mid w$ was defining $\leq$ for our lattice rather than using the usual order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3073326/472818) (the 2nd and 3rd equations), we should have

$$F(x,y,z)=\frac{\text{GCD}(x,y)\text{GCD}(x,z)\text{GCD}(y,z)}{\text{GCD}(x,y,z)^2}$$

$$=\frac{\text{LCM}(x,y)\text{LCM}(x,z)\text{LCM}(y,z)}{\text{LCM}(x,y,z)^2};$$

this corresponds to the fact that

$$\text{mid}(x,y,z)=\min(x,y)+\min(x,z)+\min(y,z)-2\min(x,y,z)$$

$$=\max(x,y)+\max(x,z)+\max(y,z)-2\max(x,y,z).$$

But $\text{mid}$ is a purely order-theoretic function; it shouldn't depend on addition or subtraction. Indeed, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1670957/472818) describes $\text{mid}$ in terms of $\max$ and $\min$. Here's a more symmetric expression:

$$\text{mid}(x,y,z)=\min(\max(x,y),\max(x,z),\max(y,z))$$

$$=\max(\min(x,y),\min(x,z),\min(y,z)).$$

Applied to the exponents in prime factorization, this gives a formula for $F$:

> $$F(x,y,z)=\text{GCD}\Big(\text{LCM}(x,y),\text{LCM}(x,z),\text{LCM}(y,z)\Big)$$
>
> $$=\text{LCM}\Big(\text{GCD}(x,y),\text{GCD}(x,z),\text{GCD}(y,z)\Big).$$

These dual expressions are sandwiched between the "meet" and "join" of $(x,y,z)$ in any lattice, and are [equal in any distributive lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties).

Using the facts that $\text{LCM}(x,0)=0$ and $\text{GCD}(x,0)=x$, we get

$$F(x,y,0)=\text{LCM}(x,y)$$

$$F(x,0,0)=0$$

$$F(0,0,0)=0.$$

---

Generalizing to $n$ variables (and arbitrary lattices), we can define functions

$$\begin{align}F_1(x_1,\cdots,x_n)&=\text{GCD}\Big(\text{LCM}(x_1),\text{LCM}(x_2),\text{LCM}(x_3),\cdots,\text{LCM}(x_n)\Big) \\ F_2(x_1,\cdots,x_n)&=\text{GCD}\Big(\text{LCM}(x_1,x_2),\text{LCM}(x_1,x_3),\text{LCM}(x_2,x_3),\cdots,\text{LCM}(x_{n-1},x_n)\Big) \\ F_3(x_1,\cdots,x_n)&=\text{GCD}\Big(\text{LCM}(x_1,x_2,x_3),\cdots,\text{LCM}(x_{n-2},x_{n-1},x_n)\Big) \\ &\;\;\vdots \\ F_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n)&=\text{GCD}\Big(\text{LCM}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n)\Big)\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}G_1(x_1,\cdots,x_n)&=\text{LCM}\Big(\text{GCD}(x_1),\text{GCD}(x_2),\text{GCD}(x_3),\cdots,\text{GCD}(x_n)\Big) \\ G_2(x_1,\cdots,x_n)&=\text{LCM}\Big(\text{GCD}(x_1,x_2),\text{GCD}(x_1,x_3),\text{GCD}(x_2,x_3),\cdots,\text{GCD}(x_{n-1},x_n)\Big) \\ G_3(x_1,\cdots,x_n)&=\text{LCM}\Big(\text{GCD}(x_1,x_2,x_3),\cdots,\text{GCD}(x_{n-2},x_{n-1},x_n)\Big) \\ &\;\;\vdots \\ G_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n)&=\text{LCM}\Big(\text{GCD}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n)\Big).\end{align}$$

It follows easily that

$$\text{GCD}=F_1\mid F_2\mid F_3\mid\cdots\mid F_n=\text{LCM}$$

and

$$\text{GCD}=G_n\mid G_{n-1}\mid\cdots\mid G_2\mid G_1=\text{LCM}.$$

Furthermore, $F_k=G_{n+1-k}$ in any distributive lattice. And for the special case of a total order, $(F_1,F_2,F_3,\cdots,F_n)$ is a permutation of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n)$.